# How to parse JSON into CSV in PHP for Social Mention API

Tags: php, json, url

I need to query SocialMention.com for "Colorado Springs" and "District 11" and pull the data back into a CSV file.  I'm an old programmer but new to PHP and JSON.  Here's the simple php code:

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init('http://api.socialmention.com/search?q=%22colorado+springs%22+%22district+11%22&f=json&src[]=twitter&sentiment=true&meta=info');
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
echo $result; 
?>
```

How do I parse $result and store it in a CSV file?  I've been researching this for 6 days and have tried every example I can find with no luck.  In the examples below I keep getting an "Invalid argument in foreach" error.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad since you don't really say how you want to parse `$result`, but you're not even getting `$result` because `curl_exec` will actually print out its contents.  Instead you can set `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)`, or you can probably just use`$result = file_get_contents($url);`

Anyway, you can change the result from JSON to usable PHP data structure via `$data = json_decode($result, true)`.  The second argument forces associative arrays, which are probably better for your purposes.

Then you can write to the CSV file:

```
$fh = fopen('csvfile', 'w');
foreach ($result['items'] as $items) {
    fputcsv($fh, $items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can refer the two links too

1.[Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)

2.[php writing to csv from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752964/php-writing-to-csv-from-an-array)

```
$json_a=json_decode($string,true); //decodes json

//writes to csv
 $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_a); $i++) {
        $fields = //json object feids here
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
```